# How to delete version records of a content item in Orchard?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, version, orchardcms

I have a Orchard CMS running that is tied to a user synchronization. This sync updates each user overnight and the code begins with

```
... = mContentManager.Get<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart>(lOrchardUser.ContentItem.Id,
  Orchard.ContentManagement.VersionOptions.DraftRequired);
```

As you can see `VersionOptions.DraftRequired` is passed to the `Get()` method with creates a new draft each time the user is synchronized. It's not intended to create a new draft here so i changed it to `VersionOptions.Published` which avoids creating a new version record on each call.

But issue here is that passing `VersionOptions.DraftRequired` in the past has created around 120 version records for each user whereas there are around 1000 users in the DB.

When i now use `IContentManager.Query()` it takes considerably longer due to the high amount of versions.

My idea is to remove all versions except the published one as i don't need them but `IContentManager` doesn't provide any version removal option and deleting the records by using `IRepository<>` causes a NHibernate exception.

So my last resort was to use LINQ queries to remove the versions, this did work but i was told that using LINQ in Orchard is not recommended.

I wonder whether anyone had any issues with high amounts of version records as the longer the system runs the more data is accumulated and the system is getting slower and slower.

So, my questions are

1. is there an Orchard way to remove version records?
2. is there a way to disable versioning?

Comment: If you look at the Destroy method of the DefaultContentManager, you'll see that they create a plain query for deleting records. Maybe your best bet is querying all the records you want to have removed and then do a similar query. Just a thought

Comment: @Xceno My concern is that when i delete the records with LINQ the session handling does not recognizes this and things fall apart. Now i see that they use `SessionLocator` followed by a query followed by `ExecuteUpdate()`. Perhaps `ExecuteUpdate()` is the key here?

Comment: I assume it is, yes. But afaik this is as low level as it gets in Orchard, but I don't know of another way for deleting old version records.

However, I wonder what will happen when your records start with a version number higher than 1.

On the other hand, if you don't want versioning, why use a ContentItemVersionRecord at all?

Comment: @Xceno I dont "use" the ContentItemVersionRecord. It's an Orchard user content item thereby versioning is implied, i never actively told Orchard "use versioning".

Comment: Oh sorry, it seemed like a custom item with a UserPart attached to me.

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: @Xceno I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there seems no Orchard way to do this, i deleted the versions with the following LINQ 2 SQL code:

```
  public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult RemoveVersions()
  {
    // select user ids, an alternate way is to retrieve user IDs via content manager but this takes a veeeeery long time due
    // to the need of querying all versions
    //
    // var lOrchardUserIDs = mContentManager
    //  .Query<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart, Orchard.Users.Models.UserPartRecord>(Orchard.ContentManagement.VersionOptions.AllVersions)
    //  .List()
    //  .Select(u => u.Id)
    //  .ToList()
    var lOrchardUserIDs = mUserRepository.Fetch(u => true).Select(u => u.Id).ToList();

    foreach (var lOrchardUserID in lOrchardUserIDs)
    {
      var lContentItemVersionRecords =
        (from r in DataContext.ContentItemVersionRecords where r.ContentItemRecord_id == lOrchardUserID select r).ToList();

      if (lContentItemVersionRecords.Count > 1)
      {
        foreach (var lContentItemVersionRecord in lContentItemVersionRecords)
        {
          if (lContentItemVersionRecord.Number == 1)
          {
            if (lContentItemVersionRecords[lContentItemVersionRecords.Count - 1].Published)
            {
              lContentItemVersionRecord.Latest = true;
              lContentItemVersionRecord.Published = true;
            }
          }
          else
            DataContext.ContentItemVersionRecords.DeleteOnSubmit(lContentItemVersionRecord);
        }
      }
    }

    DataContext.SubmitChanges();

    return Content("Done");
  }
```