# Sudden drop in Orchard website performance

Tags: orchardcms

I am putting the finishing touches on a fairly large website that utilises taxonomies heavily as well as a number of custom content types that reference them.

It is currently configured to use SQL Server 2008R2 on a relatively powerful dedicated IIS box.

It has been performing quite well until suddenly (without seemingly making any major changes), it started to perform very poorly.

Loading the home page, which displays a selection of taxonomy Terms takes up to 4-5 minutes to load! I know I can cache pages (and will), but surely something is wrong if it is taking that long?

More recently, the Admin pages have started to perform the same way. I'm beginning to think it may be something to do with the ContentItem_Version table - could removing hte historical rows speed things up?

Has anyone else experienced issues like this and if so, how did you manage to overcome them?

Any help or suggestions gratefully recieved!

Comment: Are you running a release or debug build?

Comment: Release on the server, debug on local. But neither makes any difference. I think it's got something to do with the taxonomy pulling all the other related stuff into the Model. It's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Try the MiniProfiler module to help debug. It will help you narrow down if performance issues are coming from the database, shape rendering, or drivers. A quick thing to check are custom drivers and making sure drivers only run if needed, all the long running processes should be [deferred to shape rendering](https://orcharddojo.net/orchard-resources/Library/DevelopmentGuidelines/BestPractices/Orchard).

Comment: You mention it might be the version table performance. When querying content items are you only querying for the Latest Version/Published, or All Versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply some indexing on your site database, and since your application is using taxonomies heavily as you mentioned, the first thing you must try is to add the index on "TermContentItem" table, you must add the following fields to the same index:

- Field
- TermRecord_id
- TermsPartRecord_id

Hope this will help you, if not, please include some statistics of your database (like: number of "ContentItem" records, number of "TermContentItem" records ... etc) in your reply.

Comment: I've done something similar on different Orchard DBs. An index will greatly improve the performance. I always add an index via migration since then.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm beginning to think it may be something to do with the ContentItem_Version table - could removing hte historical rows speed things up?

Yes, querying the versions can take some time, here's my related issue with a solution how to delete the version records:

[How to delete version records of a content item in Orchard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35486133/3936440)